# How can I get trusted pfx certificate for my msix file? That certificate should be trusted for all windows users not only for me locally

Tags: certificate, desktop, pfx, msix, appinstaller

I have been developing a flutter desktop application. I'm going to deliver it to users in msix format, but when it comes to installation, it's not possible to install it because of its certificate is untrusted for other users.
I need to get somehow trusted pfx certificate that make my msix app available and trusted for all users.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options here:

1. Publish to the Microsoft Store
2. Buy a code-signing certificate (Might be cheap for open-source, otherwise $100+ per year)
3. Use a self-signed certificate.

To use a self-signed certificate this certificate needs to be installed/trusted on **each** computer the app gets installed before you start the installation.

You could for example create an unsigned (classic/non-appx) installer that installs your certificate by using `CertUtil.exe` and then invokes your appinstaller.